# How do I enable user interaction in two overlapped UIViews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, user-interaction

I have two overlapping UIViews, and I want both to respond to user touches. At the moment, only the last view that was loaded responds.

How do I get both to respond to touch events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, since I don't need that both responds at the same time, I made a workaround. I used the methods bringSubViewToFront: and sendSubViewToBack:. This methods made the work.

Answer (score 1):

you could provide a simple protocol which sends all touch events from the first view to the view in the background. So let the view in the background be a delegate of the first view would be a very simple approach.

Otherwise override the method `touchesBegan:withEvent:` of the view in the front and call the corresponding method of the view in the background.

Cheers,
anka

Comment: Hi @anka , using your answer, I tried to use the background view as delegate for the front view. And I call the touches method of the delegate from the front view. But nothing happens. What I have is UITextView in the background and UIView in the front.

Answer (score 1):

If you call touchesBegan/Moved/Ended on super after you handle them I think you will achieve what you want.